# Given a known value in a key-value pair, extract the value of the next key-value pair in a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, keyvaluepair

I have a list of dictionaries with each dictionary containing two key-value pairs as shown (this is only a small subset of the list)

```
G=[{j:0,vi:0},{j:1,vi:1},{j:2,vi:2},{j:3,vi:3}]
```

I'm using an If statement to find out if the current vi already exists in the list of dictionary

```
if any('vi' in d.keys() for d in G]:
```

Then I want to get the j value of that particular dictionary that contains the current vi. 
Thus if vi is 1, I want to get the 1 from j:1.
This j value will be used as a column pointer for the matrix I'm building.
I'm not sure how to go about this. Any pointers would help.

Note that the G list of dictionaries keeps growing with each iteration

i have tried various key-value extract answers here but they are all for extracting a specific key or value and not for another key or value in the same dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

> if vi in G.viewvalues():

You wanted:

```
if any('vi' in d
       for d in G):
```

You tagged the question as python3, but used a python2 language feature.

Possibly you want to write a generator function
with behavior like this:

```
for d in G:
    if d.get('vi') == current_vi_value:
        yield d['j']
```

Comment: oh thanks, will fix that. Any suggestions on how the extract the value from the next key-value pair.